# How to make a subset of nodes in JUNG to appear in a linear line?

Tags: java, swing, jung

I am trying to build a graph in JUNG such that some of the nodes in the graph appear and layout differently.

This is the code I have so far:

```
package example.ordering;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import org.apache.commons.collections15.Transformer;
import org.apache.commons.collections15.functors.ChainedTransformer;

import edu.uci.ics.jung.algorithms.layout.FRLayout;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.Graph;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.SparseGraph;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.VisualizationViewer;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.renderers.VertexLabelAsShapeRenderer;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        frame.add(createGraph());
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        frame.pack();

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private static JPanel createGraph() {

        // TODO fill in the code to create a graph with nodes and order them.
        Graph<GraphNode, String> g1 = new SparseGraph<GraphNode, String>();

        GraphNode A = new GraphNode("A", "u");
        GraphNode B = new GraphNode("B", "u");
        GraphNode a = new GraphNode("a", "l");
        GraphNode b = new GraphNode("b", "l");

        g1.addEdge("AB", A, B);
        // g1.addEdge("CD", "C", "D");

        g1.addEdge("Aa", A, a);
        g1.addEdge("Bb", B, b);

        FRLayout<GraphNode, String> layout = new FRLayout<GraphNode, String>(g1);
        VisualizationViewer<GraphNode, String> vv = new VisualizationViewer<GraphNode, String>(
                layout);

        VertexLabelAsShapeRenderer<GraphNode, String> vlasr = new VertexLabelAsShapeRenderer<GraphNode, String>(
                vv.getRenderContext());

        vv.getRenderContext().setVertexShapeTransformer(vlasr);
        vv.getRenderContext().setVertexLabelTransformer(
                new ChainedTransformer<GraphNode, String>(
                        new Transformer[] { new MyLabeller() }));
        vv.getRenderer().setVertexLabelRenderer(vlasr);

        return vv;
    }

}

class GraphNode {
    public String value;
    public String type;

    public GraphNode(String value, String type) {
        this.value = value;
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return value;
    }

}

class MyLabeller implements Transformer<GraphNode, String> {

    public String transform(GraphNode arg0) {
        if (arg0.type.equals("u")) {
            return arg0.value;
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }

}
```

[image]

Now **A** and **B** appear as proper rectangles with labels whereas the lowercase **a** and **b** appear as small tiny dashes as they have no label.

What I would like to have is the small case nodes (with type 'l') all appear at the same level sorted alphabetically.

Comment: Congratulations on asking question #4,000,000

Comment: What do you mean "at the same level"? Are you talking about the layout of the graph (the specific position of every node) or the appearance of the nodes?

Comment: @sdasdadas By same level(and only in this case) I mean that they have the same y coordinate (per se). I know I can lock the absolute position of node but that only works when there is a small number of nodes. Otherwise, it kind of gets messy and non-linear.

Comment: @sdasdadas Generally, what I am looking for is that I can lets say have a `FRLayout` for 'a' and 'b', where as an `ISOMLayout` for 'A' and 'B'

Comment: You can modify the existing layouts with an if statement and only process a subset of the nodes you like. However, the problem with applying FRLayout to half of the nodes, and ISOMLayout to the other half is that the positioning of the nodes between the two groups might overlap. The two layouts won't be able to communicate with each other.

The best solution would be to write a custom layout (which isn't that hard). Can you describe the rules your vertices should follow? (eg. lowercase vertices always appear 30 degrees left of...)

That would make it easier to customize.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `AggregateLayout` as demonstrated in this sample: http://jung.sourceforge.net/site/jung-samples/xref/edu/uci/ics/jung/samples/SubLayoutDemo.html